# How can set div with position absolute height 100% & vertical middle?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a video 100% with a legend with absolute position height 100% and aligned to the medium, the problem is that fits 100% height of the section, I seek not do half querys, I want you to naturally suits

here my example of what I try to do

```
#parent {display: table;}

#child {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uvc33Lvn/

Comment: Can you provide a mock-up of what you're trying to achieve. It's hard to tell from what you've posted so far.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kudeL6dz/ this example but without two divs less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

**HTML**

```html
<section>
    <div id="video-wrap" class="autoplay">
        <video nocontrols="" loop="">
            <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="legend-video">
            <h1>Pipoipoipo</h1>
            <p>iopipoiopop 2014</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur porta dictum turpis, eu mollis justo gravida ac. Proin non eros blandit, rutrum est a, cursus quam. Nam ultricies, velit ac suscipit vehicula, turpis eros sollicitudin lacus, at convallis mauris magna non justo. Etiam et suscipit elit. Morbi eu ornare nulla, sit amet ornare est. Sed vehicula ipsum a mattis dapibus. Etiam volutpat vel enim at auctor.</p>
            <p>Aenean pharetra convallis pellentesque. Vestibulum et metus lectus. Nunc consectetur, ipsum in viverra eleifend, erat erat ultricies felis, at ultricies mi massa eu ligula. Suspendisse in justo dapibus metus sollicitudin ultrices id sed nisl.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.legend-video {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 30%;
    overflow: auto;
}
video {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;    
}
#video-wrap {
    position: relative;
}
```

Primarily what I did was re-arranged some of your markup with a touch up on some CSS.

I moved your `.legend-video` inside the container element for the video. Then set `.legend-video` to `position: absolute` so it doesn't take up any space inside of `#video-wrap`. Now all we have to do is position and stretch out `.legend-video` to our liking. To make sure `.legend-video` is the full height of `#video-wrap` we set the properties `top`, `right` and `bottom` to `0`. That tells the element to be zero pixels from the top, right or bottom edges of the parent element's edges.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uvc33Lvn/7/